# How to wrap the validation message span in div and render the container based on the validation?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How to wrap the validation message span in div and render the container based on the validation.

```
   <div id="name_validationMessage"
         class="k-widget k-tooltip k-tooltip-validation field-validation-error"
         style="margin: 0.5em;" role='alert'>
        <span class='k-icon k-warning'></span>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
        <div class='k-callout k-callout-n'></div>
    </div>
```

---

In the Above HTML:
The div appear in the first place as empty with background color but I want to tie it with the visibility of the validation message span.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check `name_validationMessage` on form submit event.
if it has a span with `field-validation-error` class, show `name_validationMessage`.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var name_validationMessage = $('#name_validationMessage');
        $('form').submit(function () {
            if (name_validationMessage.find('.field-validation-error').get().length > 0) {
                name_validationMessage.show();
            }
            else {
                name_validationMessage.hide();
            }
        });
    });
```